# Pass a string from a JAVA application to a php variable

Tags: java, php

Assuming that we have a `JAVA` application that connects and exchanges some `XML`'s with an `EPP server`.

That application writes the data that it receives from the server into files.
It creates a file for each response it gets, according to `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
The name of the file is `currentMillis`.

Now, since I'm going to need a `php` script to locate those files, can I simply make the
`JAVA` application return a value (that of the `currentMillis`) and somehow from the `php` script parse that into a PHP variable?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the Java and PHP communication over HTTP. So convert the java code that returns the time into a [Servlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

Then invoke the servlet from your PHP code and capture the data returned into a PHP variable.